# iphone pdf app that doesn't scroll

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I often use my iphone to scan through presentations that are stored as pdfs. Often, the information on the following page of a document is the same as the previous page plus some extra information. What I find annoying is that the pdf readers I have tried so far all "animate" the scrolling to the next page. All I want is an instant "next page", like one gets when one makes the presentation.

I have looked at myPDFs and Adobe acrobat.

Can anyone suggest an app that has ability?

Answer (score 1):

[iBooks](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ibooks/id364709193), the free ebook reading app from Apple, paginates both ebooks (in epub format) and pdfs. It is not instant, though.